# Switching color and grayscale mode for \includegraphics

Tags: graphics, pdftex, pdf, color

Suppose I have a document that includes a lot of colorful PDFs. Now I'd like to easily switch between "color" version and "greyscale version". I'm aware of `\DeclareGraphicsRule`, but I think this needs more tweaking. See the MWE below.

```
% engine: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx}

\iftrue
% code for "color" version
\else
% code for "grayscale" version
\fi

\begin{document}

\includegraphics{z4z.pdf}

\end{document}
```

You can use any image you want, but the one I used is here: http://kmlinux.fjfi.cvut.cz/~hejdato1/z4z.pdf

The command that can be used to convert image to greyscale is e.g.

```
convert -density 600 #1.pdf -colorspace Gray #2.pdf
```

Last but not least, it would be nice if it worked both with and wihout the `.pdf` extension in `\includegraphics`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a classical vector drawing (`z4z.pdf`). With the command line with `convert` (`ImageMagick`) the image is converted to a bitmap. PDF can also contain bitmaps.
A better way is using `Inkscape`. It has an option to convert to the colors to the gray color model. Save again as PDF, see below.

I would use two different directories, the first directory contains the color images, the second directory the grayscale images. Then it is easy to switch between them using `\graphicspath`. The current directory should be free of these images, otherwise they would be found first.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx}

\iftrue % color
  \graphicspath{{img-color/}}
\else % grayscale
  \selectcolormodel{gray}
  \graphicspath{{img-gray/}}
\fi

\begin{document}
  \includegraphics[scale=.5]{z4z}
\end{document}
```

In case of grayscale the example also switches to the gray color model for the colors controlled by package `xcolor`. Also black/white is possible with option `monochrome`, but the option is needed at loading time of the color packages:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

%\iftrue % color
\iffalse
  \graphicspath{{img-color/}}
\else % grayscale
  \PassOptionsToPackage{monochrome}{xcolor}
  \graphicspath{{img-gray/}}
\fi

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
  \includegraphics[scale=.5]{z4z}
\textcolor{yellow}{yellow}
\textcolor{red}{red}
\textcolor{blue}{blue}
\end{document}
```