# Color Image to Grey scale and RGB to CMYK Conversion

Tags: dvips

How can I convert all color images to Grey scale? I am using MikTeX 2.9, LaTeX->dvips->ps2PDF for conversion.

Also, please advise if possible to change all RGB color image to CMYK format...

Comment: maybe have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3322/is-there-a-way-to-convert-an-image-to-grayscale

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29227/can-includegraphics-be-used-to-change-an-image-color

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73548/switching-color-and-grayscale-mode-for-includegraphics

Comment: My exact requirement was what Mr. Herbert Voss suggested, i.e.,  "if you run the latex->dvips->ps2pdf sequence it can be done from within latex – Herbert Sep 20 '11 at 8:07 ", but I couldn't see the solution from that post...

Comment: @MadyYuvi You have to read the answers, not only comments: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28960/124577